# Count the number of ways to give candies to two different group of people. One wants an even number, the other is always satisfied.

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to satisfy $b$ people wanting an even number of candies and $c$ people wanting any number of candies if you have $n$ candies.
So I thought about generating functions:
$$A(x)=(x^0+x^2+ \dots +x^{2n})^b(x^0+x^1+ \dots +x^n)^c= \frac{1}{(1-x^2)^b(1-x)^c} $$
I basically need to convert it into an infinite series of the form $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nx^n$$ and find the $$c_n$$ Answer should be computable for $$n \leq 10^9$$ modulo $7340033$ in under $1$ second with $b$, $c$ less than $50000$.

Answer (score 0):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{(1-x^2)^b}\cdot\frac{1}{(1-x)^c}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-b}{k}(-x^2)^j\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-c}{j}(-x)^j\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{b+k-1}{k}x^{2k}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{c+j-1}{j}x^j\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{{2k+j=n}\atop{k,j\geq 0}}\binom{b+k-1}{k}\binom{c+j-1}{j}\right)x^n\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (2) we apply the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q
  \end{align*}
- In (3) we use the *[Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series)* of two power series.

*Hint:* Note, the  series $\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^b}=\left(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots\right)^b$.